# Register Windows service as stopped

Tags: c#, windows-services

I install Windows Service with following code:

```
ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceProcess(serviceName, serviceArgs));
```

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tks2stkt(v=vs.110).aspx) I see, that this method also call `OnStart` method on service. But I want to install service as stopped and later start it manually.

Comment: what if you stop service after install? will that work for you?

Comment: @Viru it's an option, but i'm afraid that service can do some actions before stop that is not good for my application. So I try to find solution to avoid this

Comment: Ya got it but in that case you have to override onStart method and provide your own implementation where you can check if it is first time start if yes then do not call start

Comment: Please try code I posted...I have not tested it so let me know it it works or not

Comment: You can use the ServiceInstaller class which does not autostart services - See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceinstaller(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched our project and found custom installer. I overrided method `OnCommitted` and check parameter `Delayed` to start service now or do it later by hand.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class CustomInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public CustomInstaller()
    {
        _installProcess = new ServiceProcessInstaller { Account = ServiceAccount.NetworkService };
        _installService = new CustomServiceInstaller(typeof(ServiceImplementation));

        //  Remove built-in EventLogInstaller:
        _installService.Installers.Clear();

        Installers.Add(_installProcess);
        Installers.Add(_installService);
    }

    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        //install
        base.Install(stateSaver);
    }

    protected override void OnCommitted(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        var delyed = bool.Parse(GetContextParameter(@"Delayed"));

        if (!delyed)
        {
            new ServiceController(GetContextParameter(ServiceNameKey)).Start();
        }
    }

    private string GetContextParameter(string parameterKey)
    {
        var parameterValue = Context.Parameters[parameterKey];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterValue))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, MissingRequiredParameterErrorMessage, parameterKey));
        return parameterValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static InitialStartDone = false; // declared in service class
protected Overrride void OnStart(string[] args);
{
    if(!InitialStartDone)
    {
        InitialStartDone = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnStart(args);
    }
}
```

Try overriding the default behavior of on start and use static variable to detect if it is called first time

Comment: I don't think this will work. **Every** time you start the service, InitialStartDone will be false and hence the service will never start!

Comment: I reserach a bit more and `OnStart` method is too late, service is already started. Below I posted solution that works for me.